# I am using the DaCe framework in Python. How can I edit the debug info of a tasklet, either at creation or after its creation?

Tags: performance, portability, dataflow

I am using the DaCe framework to create SDFGs from other pieces of code. Therefore, when I am translating the code, I need the tasklet debug info to relate to the original code rather than the python code doing the translating.

Is that possible in DaCe, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating Tasklets using the SDFG API, you can use the `debuginfo` keyword argument of `add_tasklet` or the other API calls to set the right line/column information. See an example [in the Python DaCe frontend](https://github.com/spcl/dace/blob/0c51cd420d9e77bf99dc6f8cf199810122a33c9d/dace/frontend/python/newast.py#L771).